# Counting number of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given a string of digits, we have to find the number of sequences which satisfy the following criteria:

```
Numbers are listed in the strictly increasing order;
Every Number is a positive integer number;
There are no leading zeros.
```

For example, given the number 123434, we can split is as :

```
"123434" = "123434" (maybe the given sequence is just one big number)
"123434" = "1" + "23434"
"123434" = "12" + "3434"
"123434" = "123" + "434"
"123434" = "1" + "23" + "434"
"123434" = "1" + "2" + "3434"
"123434" = "1" + "2" + "3" + "434"
"123434" = "1" + "2" + "3" + "4" + "34"
```

How can we find the solution to this problem (any approach may be considered valid). I had thought of marking all the increasing numbers and then counting the ways for each configuration, but that takes a lot of time.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  If, say, the given number was $12$ then would the possible "splits" be $(1,2),(12),(21)$ making the answer $3$?  Or must I preserve the initial order, ruling out the $(21)$ and making the answer $2$?

Comment: @lulu no, you can't change the order: only (1,2) and (12)

Comment: And if the given number were $121$ then I could make $(1,21)$ or $(121)$ but not $(1,2,1)$ or $(12,1)$ so the answer would be $2$ again?

Comment: Assuming I have it right, the way I would program it is:  If the given string has length $L$ there are $L-1$ places to put dividing lines, so there are only $2^{L-1}$ possible "splits".  Now there are some ways to rule out lots of cases, for example, the length of each integer must be non-decreasing.  Still, you'll end up with a bunch of cases that have to be examined.  I doubt there is anything like a simple closed formula, but who knows?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?